# RESTful naming of concatinated words

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

We have the discussion how to design our RESTful URI's when they contain multiple words that need to be concatinated like "config values". I have read that the underscore is commonly used like "config_values" but visually I would prefer a dash like "config-values".

The question is:
Are there any arguments to use the one or the other? Or is it just a cosmetic thing that will not have any serious influence anywhere.

Comment: Changed your tag rets to rest

Answer (score 0):

I prefer camel case like in Java for request parameters and dashed naming `one-two` for path components like Stackoverflow does.